# MYSql выборка по количеству записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь составить запрос

```
            SELECT 
                statuses.name,
                Count(leads.id) as open_leads
            FROM statuses, leads
            WHERE leads.status_id=statuses.id
            GROUP BY statuses.id
```

В таблице leads есть поле contact_id. Скажите, как сделать так, чтобы запрос вывел только количество тех сделок (`Count(leads.id) as open_leads`), `contact_id` которых встречается в таблице несколько раз.
Т.е. что-то вроде 
`WHERE leads.status_id=statuses.id and leads.contact_id встречается > 1 раза`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT statuses.name,
        Count(leads.id) as open_leads
   FROM statuses, leads
  WHERE leads.status_id=statuses.id
    AND leads.contact_id IN(SELECT contact_id FROM leads
                             GROUP BY contact_id
                             HAVING count(*)>1
                           )
  GROUP BY statuses.id
```